# How to add useUnifiedtopology property to MongoClient constructor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, strapi, mongodb-atlas

(node:8041) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Answer (score 1):

With connect function:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/DATABASE', { useUnifiedTopology: true }});
```

With MongoClient:

```
var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017), { useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Simply send `options` object to second parameter.

Comment: For Strapi just add it to the empty options object in database.json